# How to get COUNT from ResultSet object?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am passing the following query to a ResultSet object:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT KEY ), SOURCE FROM MY_TBL\n" +
            "GROUP BY SOURCE\n" +
            "ORDER BY SOURCE";
```

I want to capture the counts I am getting for each SOURCE and sum them into a total. How can I capture these counts via ResultSet since COUNT isn't a column name in the ResultSet and I don't think I can return it's value via `rs.getInt("COUNT")`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getInt` is [overloaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29), use index (an `int`) instead of a column name:

```
 rs.getInt(1); // the first column is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having alias

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT KEY ) AS COUNT, SOURCE FROM MY_TBL\n" +
        "GROUP BY SOURCE\n" +
        "ORDER BY SOURCE";
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think it is better to use

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from Customer");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

int numCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think "getColumnCount" retinto number of column in a table instead of number of rows...